# Why would a requests call with a timeout hang?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have a program which queries a series of APIs in several threads. For two of the APIs (which I do not control), it happens that the thread freezes - probably on the HTTP request (I have an alert which shows me that a call has not been done for some time).

I initially thought that it would be a matter of [timeout](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts) but my code handles this, including catching the exception:

```
 while True:
    try:
        r = requests.get('http://10.10.10.1', timeout=10)
        if not r.ok:
            raise ValueError('wrong reply for API xxx: {t}, code: {c}'.format(t=r.text, c=r.status_code))
    except Exception as e:
        # cannot reach the API at all
        log.error('problem with API xxx: {e}'.format(e=e))
    else:
        (...)

    time.sleep(10)
```

With this in mind, is there a reason for the `requests` call to hang? (`requests` 2.12.4, Python 3.4+). The part of the code under `(...)` is made of very basic non-blocking data transformations.

Comment: Could it be that the result of the API request is just very big or the connection extremely slow? It won't timeout if it actually receives data and it won't return until it got everything either...

Comment: "timeout is not a time limit on the entire response download; rather, an exception is raised if the server has not issued a response for timeout seconds (more precisely, if no bytes have been received on the underlying socket for timeout seconds). If no timeout is specified explicitly, requests do not time out."

Comment: What is your `request` loop clock(which value is OK (ms,us)?)? `While True` and `timeout=10` i can't imagine `How do you combine these two features?`.Of course you can use them together but not right to reside in the same process. If you think fast process, use the socket. "request" not a solution on LOCAL  !

Comment: @dsgdfg: sorry, but I do not follow you. The `while` loop makes the call repetitive forever, the `sleep` hangs the thread for some time, while the `timeout` ensures that the `requests` call exits if there is something wrong with the other party (the API).

Comment: "The while loop makes the call repetitive forever" forever required symetrical procces ! External proccess always need a thread and status comparator function(`timeout` do nothing for you).  How to push `real-time` data ? with timeout ? `r = requests.get('http://10.10.10.1', timeout=10)` totaly wrong idea cos you only got request, need using `if client_connected : server.push_data()`, so we have same thinks ? NO!

Comment: @dsgdfg: to be honest I have no idea what you are talking about. maybe craft this as an answer so that it is more understandable for a beginner like me?

Comment: i think '10.10.10.1' not is your server. Every api got some rule ! I count (on my server) every request time (only allow 2 request per second(500ms)). `raise etc` but why ? Did you want know what happened ? Need using a thread every request for determined fuzzy `timeout`. `New_thread(try(request); Except: Add_information_to_exception_class)`  Another thread scan `exception_class_variables`.

Comment: Can you print the stack trace of where it hangs? https://github.com/niccokunzmann/hanging_threads

Comment: @User: this is a very interesting module, I did not know it. I just plugged it into my code and will fait for the hang, then update my question. Thanks!

Comment: @WoJ Did you get further?